# Reset Postgres Database on Heroku in Deploy Time

Tags: django, postgresql, heroku, gitlab-ci, heroku-postgres

I've got a Django website with PostgreSQL backend and I'm using gitlab ci/cd to test and deploy it on Heroku.

I do lots of new changes in models every time and I want the database to be cleaned before Heroku runs: `python manage.py migrate` on it.
I know that I can run `heroku pg: reset DATABASE` from my computer each time, but I am searching for a way to do this automatically as a step in deployment.

This is the content of my `.giltab-ci.yml` file:

```
image: python:3.6.5

services:
  - postgres:latest

variables:
  POSTGRES_DB: asdproject
  POSTGRES_USER: postgres
  POSTGRES_PASSWORD: asdpassword

test:
  script:
  - whoami
  - export PGPASSWORD=$POSTGRES_PASSWORD
  - apt-get update -qy
  - apt-get install -y python-dev python-pip
  - pip install -r requirements.txt
  - python manage.py test --settings=backend_settings.gitlab_runner_settings


production:
   type: deploy
   script:
      - apt-get update -qy
      - apt-get install -y ruby-dev
      - gem install dpl
      - dpl --provider=heroku --app=asd-g7 --api-key=$HEROKU_PRODUCTION_API_KEY
 only:
     - master
```

Where should I put the reset command? and how?

Answer (score 0):

Heroku's [release phase](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/release-phase) is what you're looking for. One of its primary use cases is to run database operations in conjunction with new releases. You can define a `release` process in your `Procfile`. For example, a migration for a typical rails app might look something like thi:

```
web: bundle exec puma -C config/puma.rb
worker: bundle exec sidekiq
release: bundle exec rake db:migrate
```

Whereas you would want to swap in the appropriate reset command for your application in the `release` process.

Comment: Thanks, can you provide an example for python and Django too?

Answer (score 0):

I have come up with the following solution for a similar scenario.

In **Procfile**, declare a **release** dyno that runs a bash script:

```
release: bash release-tasks.sh
web: (...)
```

Add the file **release-tasks.sh** in the root of your project.

Write Postgres SQL commands in the bash script like this, to remove all records from *mytable*:

```
#!/bin/bash

psql --dbname $DATABASE_URL --command "DELETE FROM mytable;"
```

The long answer is, Heroku will run a one-off dyno with a bash shell during release phase. Release phase runs after compilation and before deployment. You can experiment with the one-off dyno using this command:

```
heroku run bash
```

To find out what environment variables are available, run this command in the bash shell:

```
set
```